# Artifactory bundle install '/versions' file not found

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, bundler, artifactory

We are running a local Artifactory Pro installation and have `rubygems.org` configured as a Remote Repository.

When running `bundle install` in a CI Job, the local Artifactory Instance does return a `404 File not found` when querying for the `/versions` file. When doing a manual lookup in the Remote (&Cache) Repo, the file **>is present<**.

The path we pass to `bundle install` is provided by the `Set me up` Wizard and looks like this:
`https://$rtf-instance.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems-remote/versions`

This was mentioned in an issue here: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16005
and should have been fixed, but it is still not working in our installation.
Can't find any mention of `RTFACT-16005` or the related `RTFACT-19012` in the Release Notes.

Repo is setup with default values, no additional config done.
Are we missing something?

---

Environment:

- debian 10 (buster)
- nginx 1.14.2
- artifactory-pro 7.15.4 / 7.15.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the gems compact index support you need to add the following system property (under $JFROG_HOME/var/etc/artifactory/artifactory.system.properties):
artifactory.gems.compact.index.enabled=true

You will need to restart Artifactory afterward.

Answer (score 2):

This can be found in JFrog Wiki, here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/RubyGems+Repositories#RubyGemsRepositories-RetrievingLatestRubyGemsPackageCompatiblewithYourRubyVersions